# iterating through a dataset and apply values from 5 of 7 columns to textboxs in an active report

Tags: vb.net, activereports

I want to iterate through a dataSet and apply each value to a textbox in an active report. i dont know if these text boxes need to be a the Group/Header area or what. i know that my code below is only retrieving the first row. how can I iterate through all rows and apply the data to text boxes that active reports manages to get multiple rows in the group section

```
    Private Sub rptUserCellPhoneSwap_ReportStart(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.ReportStart
    Me.PageSettings.Orientation = GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Document.Section.PageOrientation.Landscape
    DateTxt.Text = Now.ToShortDateString & " " & Now.ToShortTimeString
    Dim DataSet = GrabInformation(FirstName, LastName)
    UserTxt.Text = LastName + ", " + FirstName

    'For Each dr As DataRow In DataSet.Tables(0).Rows
    '    OldIMEITxt.Text = DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(dr("OldIMEI")).ToString
    '    NewIMEITxt.Text = DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(dr("NewIMEI")).ToString
    '    ReasonTxt.Text = DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(dr("SwapReason")).ToString
    '    DateRepTxt.Text = DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(dr("DateSwapped")).ToString
    '    ValueTxt.Text = DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(dr("EstimatedAccumulatedValue")).ToString

    'Next

    If Not IsNothing(DataSet) Then
        If DataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            OldIMEITxt.Text = DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("OldIMEI")
            NewIMEITxt.Text = DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("NewIMEI")
            ReasonTxt.Text = DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("SwapReason")
            DateRepTxt.Text = DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("DateSwapped")
            ValueTxt.Text = DataSet.Tables(0).Rows(0)("EstimateAccumulatedValue")
        End If
    End If



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveReports can read data from your DataSet without additional loops in code.
if you return the data table to DataSource property of report object, then it is enough to set DataField property of TextBox controls and GroupHeader section correctly to show data in report. the rendering engine will go through all data rows automatically:

```
    Private Sub SectionReport1_ReportStart(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ReportStart
    ' bind TextBox controls to fields in table
    Me.txtF1.DataField = "F1"
    Me.txtF2.DataField = "F2"
    ' set the grouping field
    Me.GroupHeader1.DataField = "F2"
    ' set the report data source
    Me.DataSource = GetSampleData().Tables(0)
End Sub

Private Function GetSampleData() As DataSet
    Dim ds = New DataSet()
    Dim dt = ds.Tables.Add("TestData")
    dt.Columns.Add("F1")
    dt.Columns.Add("F2")
    dt.Rows.Add("1", "0")
    dt.Rows.Add("2", "0")
    dt.Rows.Add("1", "1")
    dt.Rows.Add("2", "1")
    Return ds
End Function
```

if you prefer to read data row by row in "semi-automatic mode", then FetchData event handler can help here:

```
    Dim i As Integer
Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing

Private Sub SectionReport2_ReportStart(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.ReportStart
    i = 0
    ' bind TextBox controls to fields in table
    Me.txtF1.DataField = "F1"
    Me.txtF2.DataField = "F2"
    ' set the grouping field
    Me.GroupHeader1.DataField = "F2"
    dt = GetSampleData().Tables(0)
End Sub

Private Sub SectionReport2_DataInitialize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.DataInitialize
    Me.Fields.Add("F1")
    Me.Fields.Add("F2")
End Sub

Private Sub SectionReport2_FetchData(sender As Object, eArgs As FetchEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FetchData
    If dt.Rows.Count > i Then
        Me.Fields("F1").Value = dt.Rows(i)(0)
        Me.Fields("F2").Value = dt.Rows(i)(1)
        eArgs.EOF = False
    Else
        eArgs.EOF = True
    End If
    i = i + 1
End Sub

Private Function GetSampleData() As DataSet
    Dim ds = New DataSet()
    Dim _dt = ds.Tables.Add("TestData")
    _dt.Columns.Add("F1")
    _dt.Columns.Add("F2")
    _dt.Rows.Add("1", "0")
    _dt.Rows.Add("2", "0")
    _dt.Rows.Add("3", "1")
    _dt.Rows.Add("4", "1")
    Return ds
End Function
```

also, i would recommend to look at the sample with run time data binding in the ActiveReports installation package.
here is a link to the sample description on the official site:
[Unbound Data](http://arhelp.grapecity.com/webhelp/AR10/UnboundArraySample.html)

Comment: thats what i did. i set the DataSource to the returned table and set the text boxes. thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would loop through to get all rows, but in this example the only data that will be left in the textboxes will be the last row.

if you want to concatenate each rows information in the specified text box then you should have the information like this.

```
OldIMEITxt.Text = OldIMEITxt.Text & dr("OldIMEI")
```

Loop Code

```
For each dr as Datarow in DataSet.Tables(0).Rows
   OldIMEITxt.Text = dr("OldIMEI")
   NewIMEITxt.Text = dr("NewIMEI")
   ReasonTxt.Text = dr("SwapReason")
   DateRepTxt.Text = dr("DateSwapped")
   ValueTxt.Text = dr("EstimateAccumulatedValue")
Next
```